# How to remove the memory for dynamically added images in android

Tags: android

I am adding dynamically 20 images to the fragment . Here problem is when i destroy fragment and reloading, the memory was not deleting at destroy time and adding new memory for again 20 images.

my code is:

```
for(int i=0;i<machImagesCursor.getCount();i++)


        {

            machImagesCursor.moveToPosition(i);

          ImageView imageView=new ImageView(getActivity());
            imageView.setId(i);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    100, 75);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
          String imageName=machImagesCursor.getString(machImagesCursor.getColumnIndex("M_ImageName"));

          String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
                    + "/fleetsyncimages/" +imageName ;


            Log.d("image-path",path);

  imageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(path));
            hScrollView.addView(imageView);
```

}

**at onDestroy**

```
for(int i=0;i<hScrollView.getChildCount();i++)
        {

         ImageView iv=(ImageView)hScrollView.getChildAt(0);
    //  iv.setImageBitmap(null);

        Drawable d = iv.getDrawable();

            ((BitmapDrawable) d).getBitmap().recycle();
        }
```

In my logcat:  **the heap is keep on increasing.**

Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if the `onDestroy()` code is necessary, but

```
ImageView iv=(ImageView)hScrollView.getChildAt(0);
```

doesn't seem correct, you should get child `i`, instead of `0` all the time.

Are you using any other technique to save images? Like store them in an array in `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()`. `Drawable`s hold a reference to the current `Context`, so you could leak your whole context by keeping `Drawable`s between `Activity` instances.

Comment: Even I have one doubt i.e., what i was used the procedure for removing the memory for images is correct or not?\

Comment: I can't imagine you should clean them up yourself.

Comment: but, I am saving in sdcard. when I recreating(reloading) the fragment,again pictures are taken from sdcard.